# Laravel Eloquent / Carbon between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

Some background first, I have a contact model to keep track of a user's contacts, and I have an anniversary model, they are linked as `Many-to-Many` with a pivot table (Each user can decide his/her own anniversaries and then add those to a contact, so the anniversaries are not hard coded).

So each `User` hasMany `Anniversaries` and every `Contact` can have many `Anniversaries`, while an `Anniversary` can have many `Contacts`.

For example, to get upcoming birthdays for all contacts for the next x months, I use the following query:

```
    auth()->user()->contacts()->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(birthdate, "%m-%d")'), array(
        Carbon::now()->format('m-d'),
        Carbon::now()->addMonths($months)->format('m-d')))
        ->get();
```

This works perfectly. However, for the anniversaries it is a bit more complicated. An anniversary at this moment can have a frequency of `monthly`, `quarterly`, `semi-annually` and `annually`. This is stored as a string in the pivot table `anniversary_contact`.

I would like to use a similar query for this as the above one, but I am wondering if this is at all possible without having to repeat a lot of `orWhereBetween` like below:

In the below query I check for upcoming anniversaries with a frequency of `monthly` for the next 3 days:

```
    $anniversaries = auth()->user()->contacts()->get()->each(function ($contact)
    {
        $contact->anniversaries->each(function ($anniversary) {
            return $anniversary->whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d")'), array(
                Carbon::now()->format('m-d'),
                Carbon::now()->addDays(3)->format('m-d')))
                ->orWhereBetween(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d")'), array(
                    Carbon::now()->addMonths(1)->format('m-d'),
                    Carbon::now()->addDays(3)->format('m-d')))
                ->get();

                // Left the rest of the 10 "orWhereBetween" out of it in this example
        });
    });
```

Although the above repetition is a seperate issue, my main issue is this:

```
DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d")')
```

There is no `date` field in the anniversaries table, it is in the pivot table.

Main question: How to use the above query to get the results I need, from checking against the pivot date?

Bonus question: Can the above query be made "simpler" or "smaller" without having to use a lot of `orWhereBetween` statements? If I need to check an upcoming anniversary that is a monthly one, I will have 12 `orWhereBetween` statements. Can this be reduced?

Or should I forget about checking it on the database level and instead get all anniversaries and use Carbon to check against upcoming anniversaries?